# RegExp to match fraction

Tags: regex

I'm trying to perform regex to match a fraction. 
The user will input a fraction eg., 1/4, 1 1/2 10/2 so on. 
I have tested this regex and it works, but the problem is when I type in 10/2, 20/5, 30/3, 40/53 so on It does not recognized these fraction. This is my regex 
 As you can see, it first sorted out the integer and then the slash and lastly the integer after the slash.

```
   var check_zero_value = str1.match(/[1-9]\/[1-9]/g);

   if(!check_zero_value1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: `10, 20, 30, 40` are not fractions. If you want to find integers too, put the operator and the denominator in a group and make it optional.

Comment: yeah,. what I mean,. if I entered 10/2, 20/10,. it does not match. but When I input 21/2, 14/4,. it is match.

Comment: @user3627265 `[0-9]` in your regex instead `/[1-9]\/[1-9]/g` like this `/[0-9]\/[1-9]/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate both integers and fractions you can do:

```
/[1-9][0-9]*(?:\/[1-9][0-9])*/g
```

Link to ***[Fiddler](http://regex101.com/r/zT2dF9)***

If you want *only* fractions:

```
/[1-9][0-9]*\/[1-9][0-9]*/g
```

Link to ***[Fiddler](http://regex101.com/r/uR7rN1)***

Comment: The second one works for me. 
I guess the * is the one I'm missing in my regex in my attempt. Thanks

Comment: The first one has the second `*` in the wrong place, should be before `)`. Currently it matches only two-digit denominators

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to match only fractions:

```
/(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)\/[1-9][0-9]*/g
```

or this to match integers too:

```
/(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)(?:\/[1-9][0-9]*)?/g
```

In the two patterns, zero is allowed for the numerator but not for the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both you can use

```
(([1-9]\d*\_)|([1-9]\d*\/[1-9]\d*)|([1-9]\d*\_[1-9]\d*\/[1-9]\d*))
```

With this, you can validate if you receive the following cases

- The whole part, in my case I use the character "_" like a separator between the whole part and the fraction (2_, 12312_, 24353_, 234_)
- Only the fraction (9/86, 75/645, 3/21, 2/5, 4/35, 7/8)
- A whole and fraction (5_9/86, 666_75/645, 23_3/21, 1_2/5, 2_4/35, 6_7/8)

I use GOLANG, you can see my repo at github [lcuriel/fractions](https://github.com/lcuriel/fractions)

Comment: Why do you escape the underscore?

Comment: it was a requirement for that reason I need a separator between the whole part and fraction.

Comment: My question was **why** do you escape the underscore?

Comment: To avoid confusion or highlight the fact that it is an underscore and not a blank space. For example, when using vim you define a blank space \ _s